# python program not working beacuse of the "if"

Tags: python

---

### I need an answer to this problem.
i tried fixing it for like an hour and i am hopeless.
vs code told me that the problem is from the "IF" but i can't fix it.

```
while True:
    print("YOUTUBE SIMULATOR")
    print("1. search a video")
    print("2. edit video")
    choice = int(input())
        if choice == 1:
            print("Searching video...")
            print("Can't find your video!")
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Editing video...") 
            print("Can't edit your video?")
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. The `if` and `elif` need to be on the same indentation level as the `choice =` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a problem with indentation. try this:

```
while True:
    print("YOUTUBE SIMULATOR")
    print("1. search a video")
    print("2. edit video")
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
            print("Searching video...")
            print("Can't find your video!")
    elif choice == 2:
            print("Editing video...") 
            print("Can't edit your video?")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Indentation Error:
> Try This

```
while True:
    print("YOUTUBE SIMULATOR")
    print("1. search a video")
    print("2. edit video")
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        print("Searching video...")
        print("Can't find your video!")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Editing video...") 
        print("Can't edit your video?")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    print("YOUTUBE SIMULATOR")
    print("1. search a video")
    print("2. edit video")
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        print("Searching video...")
        print("Can't find your video!")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Editing video...") 
        print("Can't edit your video?")
```

Comment: I fixed your indention